# How to mix DynamicParameters and DependsOn

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

I guess I'm missing something, or I'm in someway doing something stupid, but I can't fathom it out. Assume the following two classes:

```
public class A
{
    public A(string a, string b)
    {
    }
}

public class B
{
    public B(A boris2)
    {
    }
}
```

And this `main` method:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var container = new WindsorContainer();
    container.Register(
        Component.For<A>().LifeStyle.Transient.ImplementedBy<A>().Named("Boris2")
        //.DynamicParameters((k,d)=>{
        //  d["b"] = "jkl";
        //})
        .DependsOn(new { a = "ghi", b="jkl" })
        );

    container.Register(
        Component.For<B>().LifeStyle.Transient.ImplementedBy<B>()
        .DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent("boris2", "Boris2"))
        );

    var b = container.Resolve<B>();
    Console.WriteLine("Okay");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

If I run this method as shown above, it prints `Okay`, I press return, and it exits. All is fine. However, As shown in the commented out code, I want the `b` parameter to be dynamicly computed (eventually it will be, but I just wanted to get to the nub of the issue)

So, if I make my first call to `Register` look like this instead:

```
    container.Register(
        Component.For<A>().LifeStyle.Transient.ImplementedBy<A>().Named("Boris2")
        .DynamicParameters((k, d) =>
        {
            d["b"] = "jkl";
        })
        .DependsOn(new { a = "ghi" })
        );
```

Which I *thought* would be roughly equivalent, I now get an exception:

```
Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.HandlerException was unhandled
  HelpLink=groups.google.com/group/castle-project-users
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=Can't create component 'PlayAreaCS_Con.B' as it has dependencies to be satisfied.

'PlayAreaCS_Con.B' is waiting for the following dependencies:
- Component 'Boris2' (via override) which was registered but is also waiting for dependencies.

'Boris2' is waiting for the following dependencies:
- Parameter 'b' which was not provided. Did you forget to set the dependency?

  Source=Castle.Windsor
  StackTrace:
       at Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultHandler.AssertNotWaitingForDependency()
       at Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultHandler.ResolveCore(CreationContext context, Boolean requiresDecommission, Boolean instanceRequired, Burden& burden)
       at Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.DefaultHandler.Resolve(CreationContext context, Boolean instanceRequired)
       at Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.AbstractHandler.Resolve(CreationContext context)
       at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.ResolveComponent(IHandler handler, Type service, IDictionary additionalArguments, IReleasePolicy policy)
       at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.Castle.MicroKernel.IKernelInternal.Resolve(Type service, IDictionary arguments, IReleasePolicy policy)
       at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.Resolve(Type service, IDictionary arguments)
       at Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer.Resolve[T]()
       at PlayAreaCS_Con.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Dev\PlayAreaCS_Con\PlayAreaCS_Con\Program.cs:line 49
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

I even tried moving both parameters into `DynamicParameters` and removing `DependsOn`, thinking it may be some issue with mixing the two together, but it still errors. From what I can work out, it's not invoking my lambda at all.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**

If I comment out:

```
.DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent("boris2", "Boris2"))
```

From my second `Register` call, then it works. But I do need to have several identical components registered in the container, only distinguished by name. (I've removed the other registration from the first `Register` call, since it doesn't seem to be relevant)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what to say, other than: works on my machine (with Windsor 3.2), with the original (first) code, where I just uncommented the commented out code.

Comment: Did you also remove `b` from the anonymous object in the `DependsOn` call?

Comment: That's the thing though - I'm wanting to shift from having `b` supplied as a static value in `DependsOn` to being supplied dynamicly via `DynamicParameters`

Comment: It was being supplied by dynamic parameter which takes precedence over DependsOn

Comment: Ah. I was missing that I *have* to still include it in `DependsOn`, even though the value supplied there will be overridden. In most scenarios, you can *just* supply the value in `DynamicParameters`.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried a similar scenario. I was using dynamic parameters and everything was fine.

I added named registrations and referenced some using DependsOn(ServiceOverride.ForKey) and I got a whole bunch of "is waiting for the following dependencies" errors.

Then I converted all my dynamic dependencies to the anonymous object form and everything was fine. I didn't do anything else between these steps. I'm using Windsor version 3.3.0. I'm glad it finally worked though.